# Can a wizard learn a spell from a divine scroll?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, spells, magic-items

Straight forward question, is a wizard able to learn a spell and add it to their spellbook when the scroll is divine.

This comes up because the wizard technically has to UMD a divine scroll even if the spell is on both lists.

From the [scrolls](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/scrolls/) page (which affects casting a spell)

> The spell must be of the correct type (arcane or divine). Arcane spellcasters (wizards, sorcerers, and bards) can only use scrolls containing arcane spells, and divine spellcasters (clerics, druids, paladins, and rangers) can only use scrolls containing divine spells

[Adding Spells to a Wizard’s Spellbook](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/Magic/#Adding_Spells_to_a_Wizard8217s_Spellbook)

> A wizard can also add a spell to his book whenever he encounters one on a magic scroll or in another wizard’s spellbook. No matter what the spell’s source, the wizard must first decipher the magical writing (see Arcane Magical Writings).

Comment: There is a long (and entertaining) thread on this subject [on the Paizo forums](https://paizo.com/threads/rzs2mfpr&page=1?Can-a-wizard-learn-a-spell-from-a-divine-scroll)

Comment: Also related (from a 3.5e perspective): https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/72921/can-a-wizard-learn-to-cast-cure-light-wounds-from-a-bard-scroll

Comment: @JohnP Wow, that is an indept conversation and both sides make great points

Answer (score 3):

[D20PFSRD, Scrolls](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/scrolls/)

> The spell must be of the correct type (arcane or divine). Arcane spellcasters (wizards, sorcerers, and bards) can only use scrolls containing arcane spells, and divine spellcasters (clerics, druids, paladins, and rangers) can only use scrolls containing divine spells. (The type of scroll a character creates is also determined by his class.)

While this is discussing casting a spell from a scroll, it clearly indicates that spells on scrolls retain their arcane or divine type.  Wizards and other arcane casters can't learn or cast divine spells, not even divine spells that have arcane equivalents.  There is an argument online that the wizard might be able to copy the scroll into his spellbook successfully, but if he could, he still wouldn't be able to cast it, it being a divine spell.

Answer (score 1):

### No

Spell scrolls are always either divine or arcane and that is determined by the spellcaster who created it. If they were a divine spellcaster then the scroll is divine, if arcane then arcane. If they were multi-class they have to choose at the time of creation which this scroll is and can only scribe spells of this type.

So, if a scroll is a divine scroll the wizard cannot learn any spells which may also be on their list.

Many scrolls contain spells that can only be divine or only be arcane so it’s obvious which type the scroll is. However, when a scroll contains only ambiguous spells, the GM needs to decide which it is. Sometimes, an adventure creator will forget this rule and create impossible hybrid scrolls, when I encounter that, I just call it two scrolls and split the spells appropriately.

Comment: But rules for learning a spellbook https://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/wizard/#Spellbooks says nothing about writer of the scroll. Rules on scroll creation doesn't seem to support what you wrote either. Could you quote any rule that supports your point of view?