# If a wizard Wyrm Wizard adds True Creation to his spell list via Spell Research (Ex), can he replicate it via Shades?

Tags: spells, dnd-3.5e, prestige-class

> Spell Research (Ex): One of the greatest advantages that you gain from
> consulting draconic lore is the ability to unlock magical secrets
> forbidden to other wizards. Starting at 2nd level, select one spell
> from any class's spell list (including divine spells), of a level
> equal to or lower than the highest-level arcane spell you can prepare
> and cast. You can add this spell to your arcane spellcasting class
> spell list as a spell of the same level; all other aspects of the
> spell remain unchanged. At every even-numbered level thereafter, you
> gain the knowledge and use of one additional spell in this manner.

1. Wyrm wizard adds spells to your arcane spellcasting class spell list.
2. A wizard Wyrm Wizard's arcane spellcasting class is wizard.
3. Therefore Spell Research adds True Creation to your wizard class spell list.
4. Therefore True Creation is now a wizard spell for you.
5. Shades mimics any Conjuration(Creation) wizard spell of 8th level lower.
6. Since True Creation is now a wizard spell for you, your casting of Shade can mimic True Creation

Is this correct? This will determine whether I go Runesmith or Wyrm Wizard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**No**

You cannot add True Creation to your spell list through Wyrm Wizard.

> Starting at 2nd level, select one spell from any **class's spell list** (including divine spells), of a level equal to or lower than the highest-level arcane spell you can prepare and cast.

True Creation is a Domain spell and does not appear on the Cleric spell list proper, so is not a candidate for Spell Research.

Comment: Don't Divine Crusaders have every domain spell on their class spell list? "A divine crusader casts divine spells. She may only prepare and cast spells from her chosen domain (see above). Effectively, a divine crusader has a class spell list of only nine spells (one per spell level)."

Comment: @alexstrasa82 I'm not certain Divine Crusaders have a spell list, so much as an "effective spell list". I mean, not every Divine Crusader would have the Creation domain, and the class itself uses the term "effectively" in regards to spell list contents. Not a hill I'm willing to die on, though.

Comment: I agree with you. Thanks. I'm gonna go runesmith. Effective is not the real thing.

Answer (score 4):

## The presence of archivists in a setting allows a wyrm wizard's spell research to yield *true creation*…

If the setting features no archivists then I agree with this fine [answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/204400/8610) that the wyrm wizard is sunk. The 8th-level creation domain spell ***true creation*** [conj] (*Spell Compendium* 224) otherwise only appears on the list for the domain **creation** (272). While individuals may have somehow added to their spell lists the *true creation* spell, so far as I'm aware, no base or prestige class has a spell list that includes the *true creation* spell.

If there are archivists in the setting then here's how this works. For completeness, every even level the prestige class **wyrm wizard** gains the extraordinary ability **spell research** that, in part, says

> [S]elect one spell from any class's spell list (including divine spells), of a level equal to or lower than the highest-level arcane spell you can prepare and cast. You can add this spell to your arcane spellcasting class spell list as a spell of the same level…. (*Dragon Magic* 55)

At level 1 the base class archivist gains the (presumably [natural](http://dndsrd.net/specialAbilities.html#natural-abilities)) ability **prayerbook** that, in part, says

> [A]n archivist can also add spells found on scrolls containing divine spells to his prayerbook, but he must make any rolls and spend the time required (see Adding Spells to a Wizard’s Spellbook on page 178 of the *Player’s Handbook*). The archivist can learn and thus prepare nonclerical divine spells in this fashion…. (*Heroes of Horror* 83)

In other words, an archivist who acquires a *divine scroll of true creation* (up to 1,000 gp gp) (CL 15) (5,500 gp; 0 lbs.) can use that scroll to add the *true creation* spell to his prayerbook. However, it's not the *Player's Handbook* but the *Rules Compendium* that provides the crucial information about magical writings that applies to the question. **Copied Spells**, in part, says

> Spellcasters who use spellbooks [and, by extension, prayerbooks] can add a spell to their book whenever they find one on a scroll or in another caster’s spellbook. The spell to be copied must be on the copier’s class spell list. (160)

Thus an archivist must have the *true creation* spell on his spell list. If an archivist didn't have the *true creation* spell on his spell list, then the archivist wouldn't be able to add the *true creation* spell to his prayerbook using a *divine scroll of true creation*.

(If you're not using the *Rules Compendium*, this process is much less clear—see [here](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/72952/8610). Also, this makes the archivist's spell list absurdly long, a lament shared [here](https://forum.rpg.net/index.php?threads/archivist-spell-list.339028/) and [here](https://minmaxforum.com/index.php?topic=185.0), for instance. Finally, this means that an archivist might not know the extent of his own spell list. This last may initially seem strange, but that happens even if using just the core rules: Successfully **Researching Original Spells** (*Dungeon Master's Guide* 198 and [here](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/3515/8610) and not be confused with the wyrm wizard ability) already seems to add new spells to a class's spell list—not just an individual's spell list—, totally without the class's members' knowledge. Hilarious trolling may ensue.)

To sum, a wyrm wizard who gains an iteration of the spell research ability when he's also capable of casting 8th-level spells can, by plumbing the archivist's ridiculously expansive spell list, add the *true creation* spell to that wyrm wizard's own unique spell list.

### …But a wyrm wizard's spell research adds the spell only to that wyrm wizard's spell list

The 8th-level Sor/Wiz spell [***shades***](http://dndsrd.net/spellsS.html#shades) [conj] (*PH* 276), in part, says, "This spell functions like *shadow conjuration*, except that it mimics sorcerer and wizard conjuration spells of 8th level or lower." The 4th-level Sor/Wiz spell [*shadow conjuration*](http://dndsrd.net/spellsS.html#shadow-conjuration) [conj] (*ibid.*) adds little to this, saying, "*Shadow conjuration* can mimic any sorcerer or wizard conjuration (summoning) or conjuration (creation) spell of 3rd level or lower." Here are two trains:

- **"All Aboard!":** The *shadow conjuration* spell *et al.* don't say anything about spell lists. If a particular sorcerer or wizard adds a spell to his sorcerer or wizard spell list, then that spell is now a sorcerer or wizard spell—even if it's just a sorcerer or wizard spell for that individual sorcerer or wizard. This makes any sorcerer or wizard spell added to an individual sorcerer or wizard's spell list eligible to be mimicked with that particular sorcerer's or wizard's *shadow conjuration* spell *et al.*
- **"Everbody Off!"** Because "any sorcerer or wizard conjuration… spell" and the like means that the spell must actually be on the sorcerer or wizard spell list, and the *true creation* spell isn't added to every sorcerer or wizard spell list by any officially available source, it's *never* on *the* sorcerer spell list or *the* wizard spell list even if it's on *your* sorcerer or wizard spell list. Thus, as per this fine [answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/204399/8610), it can't be mimicked with the *shades* spell.

Ask the DM which train he prefers.

---

> #### Sidebar: So you've added *true creation* to your own spell list
>
> If the *true creation* spell is on a certain specific sorcerer's or wizard's sorcerer or wizard spell list—like yours, for instance, through a wyrm wizard's spell research ability—, then you can cast the *true creation* spell, you can activate magic items as if the *true creation* spell were on your appropriate spell list (because it is), and you can trigger the *true creation* spell so as to create magic items that have the spell as a prerequisite for their creation—and if one of those magic items is a scroll, it'll even be an *arcane scroll of true creation*.
>
> However, the vast majority of wizards can't copy the *true creation* spell from your spellbook into their spellbooks (according to the *Rules Compendium* anyway). Sorcerers and wizards generally won't be able to activate magic items you create with the spell trigger activation method if the *true creation* spell must be found on their spell lists. And sorcerers and wizards must make Use Magic Device skill checks to employ that scroll. (One of the requirements [scroll activation](http://dndsrd.net/magicItemsSSW.html#scroll-activation) is that the "user must have the spell on his or her class list" (*DMG* 238).)

---

***Note:** Personally, I think that "All Aboard!" is more persuasive but that "Everybody Off!" makes for a more balanced game.*

Answer (score 1):

## No.

> This spell functions like shadow conjuration, except that it mimics **sorcerer and wizard** conjuration spells of 8th level or lower.

True Creation, even if it is on "your arcane spellcasting class spell list", is not a sorcerer or wizard conjuration spell. To you, it is an arcane spell which you can prepare and cast, but it is not on THE sorcerer or wizard spell list.

Comment: Can a spell be on my wizard class spell list and not be a wizard spell? I think there might be a rule that clarifies the matter. I'm a go hunt for it.

Comment: @alexstrasa82 Could you then scribe the spell, and another wizard learn it from your scroll? If it is a wizard spell, then that should be possible.

Comment: Rules Compendium p.160. " Spellcasters who use spellbooks can add a spell to their book whenever they find one on a scroll or in another caster’s spellbook. The spell to be copied must be on the copier’s class spell list." So to answer your question. If that wizard has true creation on his class spell list then yes he can. If not then no. How does that affect your opinion on the question? (ignore the other answer because it made the whole thing moot XD.)

Comment: @alexstrasa82 Are you arguing that every wizard has a unique wizard class list, which is not THE wizard class list? That seems to be what my answer is arguing, as well. ;)

Comment: I see. So are you in fact right that Shades mimics only THE wizard spells and not ANY wizard spell? Actually does having True Creation on my spell list make it a "wizard spell"? You know what, thank you for your time. I'm just gonna give up and not think about it since it's moot anyways. XD. Thank you for your time.

Comment: @alexstrasa82 Honestly, I'm making what I believe to be the strongest argument against. The case "for" is pretty straightforward, and usually made with the combo Shadowcraft Mage/Miracle in mind. That particular build could (conceivably) use it from a cantrip slot as an 12th level character. Dragons, don't go there. Have a discussion thread on the topic: https://forums.giantitp.com/showthread.php?653606-How-to-Shadowcraft-Illusionist-Killer-Gnome-Miracle-trick